# what are the pitfalls of storing Viewstate in session or DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have read that you can do it, but would this really improve performance of the page, or would it bring more performance overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewstate data is information about the page that is encrypted and serialized into a hidden tag on the page.

If you could store it in the session these are some of the problems/pitfalls:

- The information still has to be encrypted/decrypted and serialized/deserialized from memory
- If you have a lot of users and your session data is stored in process or even using a state server, you're going to max out the memory on these servers with viewstate data.
- If you're using SQL Server for session state this obviously gets worse (see below).

If you could store it in SQL Server these would be some of the problems:

- Again, information still has to be serialized/deserialized (not necessarily encrypted/decrypted since it's not output to the page), but in this case it has to be read/written from a SQL DB. You will incur overhead in both transmission to/from the DB and I/O when reading/writing from/to the DB.

Comment: man, great points out there, so i think the best thing to do with viewstate is to compress it, and minimize using it when possible

Comment: Yes, if you can minimize using it altogether then that would be your best bet.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a good article by Scott Hanselman about storing ViewState information in the Session object:

[Moving ViewState to the Session Object and more Wrongheadedness](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx)